# Delphi/Cpp Equivalent to RawURLEncode in PHP

Tags: php, delphi, c++builder, urlencode, html-encode

I was looking for a equivalent function to PHP RawURLEncode (and Decode) in cpp builder (or delphi).

I use the following string to test: `_%_&_+_=_ _"_'_a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_` (I wish to encode only var values, not a entire URL)

The rawurlencode returns: `_%25_%26_%2B_%3D_%20_%22_%27_a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_`

I have tried without success:

- TIdURI::ParamsEncode: `_%25_&_+_=_%20_%22_'_a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_`
- TIdURI::PathEncode: `_%25_&_%2B_=_%20_%22_'_a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_`
- TIdURI::URLEncode: Error: No Protocol (Needs full path)
- HTTPApp::HTMLEncode: `_%_& amp;_+_=_ _& quot;_'_a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_` (space added after "&")
- Wininet::WinHTTPEncode: Function not found in unit
- IdGlobal::URLEncode: Function not found in unit
- SynaCode::URLEncode: Unit not found in XE2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP's `RawURLEncode` is an implementation of [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). My websearch for that yields this [Delphi unit](https://www.assembla.com/code/delphi-doodlings/subversion/nodes/58/trunk/URIEncode/UURIEncode.pas) which claims to implement RFC 3986.

I tested it on your input:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  UURIEncode in 'UURIEncode.pas';

begin
  Writeln(URIEncode('_%_&_+_=_ _"_''_a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_'));
  Readln;
end.
```

The output was:

```
_%25_%26_%2B_%3D_%20_%22_%27_a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_
```

The key to my successful websearch was found in the PHP documentation for [`RawURLEncode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) where is states:

> URL-encode according to RFC 3986

Comment: Downloads [UURIEncode.pas](https://www.assembla.com/code/delphi-doodlings/subversion/nodes/25/trunk/URIEncode/UURIEncode.pas)

Comment: You asked for C++ Builder or Delphi. I gave you Delphi. Now that you know what to search for I'm sure you can find a clean C++ implementation of RFC 3986. It's really very simply indeed. I even left instructions at the bottom of the answer as to how to perform the same websearch that I did.  ;-)

Comment: I already have "home" encoding functions (for flash, cpp and php), in fact, I was searching for libraries to work with more standardized and universal functions. In this scenario, seems better maintain old ones, but I'm grateful for your help.